# Need Mysql Query ( Thread Changed)

Tags: mysql

I have changed my thread as my last thread also same like that. But actually this is my requirement.

I have n number of users with different articleId.
If I pass the articleId, I want to get the results like how many different users viewed that article.

table1:

```
recId   userId   articleId     
-----   ------    -------- 
1        10111        102    
2        10121        102    
3        10111        102       
4        10121        105        
5        10111        102        
6        10122        105
```

table2:

```
userId     jobtitle        
-----       ------            
10111       Engineer          
10121       Doctor
10122       Professor
```

If I pass the articleId as "102" from Table1, It should return the details like how many times that particular article viewed by different users like:

```
jobtitle   total 
-----      ------     
Engineer    3 
Doctor      1 
Professor   1
```

if i pass articleid as "105", result will be like this:

```
jobtitle   total 
-----      ------     
Doctor     1
Professor  1
```

How to write query for the above results?

Thanks in advance

- Gnaniyar Zubair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT jobtitle, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON ( table1.userId = table2.userId )
WHERE articleId = <your articleid>
GROUP BY table2.jobtitle
```

Comment: this is very helpful tome peter. thanks a lot to you and stackoveflow

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  jobtitle, COUNT(recID) as total
  FROM table1 a
  INNER JOIN table2 b
  ON
    a.userId = b.userId
  GROUP BY
    jobtitle
  WHERE articleId = ?
```